# Getting error Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, sql-server, data-binding

I'm trying to copy the data from sql table "checkin "  to auto fill in on a form in a textbox  .. on a button click

```
DataSet ds = null;

private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tblNamesBS.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
     textBox2.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", tblNamesBS,"GuestName"));
}
```

Comment: where do you fill `ds`?

Comment: Let me see throught my Crystal Ball and find the solution for your question. Ahhh ... wait I got it: ds is null.

Comment: @inxs Your Crystal Ball must be newer than mine, I can't even work out the question.

Answer (score 3):

`ds` starts off as `null`, and you show no code that would make `ds` anything *other* than `null`. Thus indeed, `ds.Tables[0]` will explode with a `NullReferenceException`.

Make `ds` something non-`null`.

Comment: thats wat i want to know how to make it non null :P

Comment: @user2430070 what have you tried? what do you *want* it to contain?

Comment: tblNamesBS.DataSource = ds.Tables[0] i want to put a table name "CheckIn" .. at ds.Tables[0] like dis ds.tables[CheckIn] .. but its showing an error  'Hotel_Essencia.CheckIn' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'

Comment: You should do a C# and .NET Tutorial first. No offense but this is a QA forum and no C# Beginner course.

Comment: @user2430070 I kinda have to agree with inxs here - there are a million and twenty "how to do data access" resources on the web; and *personally* I would say "the first step is: don't use `DataSet`"

Comment: @inxs :P ahhh yea i know :P :D

Answer (score 2):

You cant use `ds` before setting it to an object....

Therefore, this call is invalid `ds.Tables[0];` -> You are trying to acces Tables from ds, when ds is null

Answer (score 0):

Like the other guys said you need to instantiate ds before you can use it.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
```